# Use Signature Pad for DocuSign Inperson Signers

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusignconnect

When signer request to sign a envelope it shows 4 options like select style, draw, upload and Use Signature Pad.
example : Email Signers in the Docusign for signing new person we choose adopt new option. inside adopt new by default for email signers to be set as ‘Select Style’.
How to set Use Signature Pad for InPerson Signers by default, instead of using  email signers.

I have already searched the internet but I can't find anything, can anyone help me.

Comment: Please show the relevant code to make this a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.